# Animating subviews in an interactive transition from the UITableView to a UIView

Tags: ios, ios7, transition

For an iOS7-only app, I have a UITableView (though it would be academic to change it to a UICollectionView if that will help) where the cells look like this:

```
+----------------------------------+=======+
| Label1                           | sub-  |
| Label2     Label3                | view  |
+----------------------------------+=======+
```

I want to transition to a second view, where the subview is zoomed out to be larger, and the label positions change, something more like this:

```
          +----------+
          |          |
          | subview  |
          |          |
          +----------+
             Label1
             Label2
             Label3
```

This is similar to the iOS7 Calendar app, where views are transitioning and animating the parts on the way. I know I'll need to implement `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, but I'm conceptually having problems with how something like this would work. Do I hide the cell's subviews, replace them with the new view's subviews but in the same place, then animate those? Or is there a less convoluted way? Any sample code would be appreciated, as all of the examples I've found are not carrying subviews over from one view to the other.

ETA: The more I think about this, the more I wonder: is this better handled with a UICollectionView with a flow layout, and simply have the detail be an animated-in resizing of the cell to the full size of the screen?

Comment: Do you mean that you're moving between view controllers?

Comment: Yes. I'm using a UINavigationController. Tapping the cell in the UITableView will push a detail UIViewController onto the stack, and I want to use the new animated transitions in iOS7 to do so.

Comment: I've been messing with this same thing today.  Only thing I've found so far, and I don't like it as it feels hackish, was in my UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol class to import my destination class, expose the subivew properties as public, then in animateTransition: to adjust their frames/scale.   It works, but I am not comfortable with it as a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently thinking that I'll basically be replicating the views in the cell on the detailview, and on the transition, hide the cell views and show the detailview views, with the background transparent, then fade in the background as I animate the detailview views into position, rather than actually sharing views among controllers.

Comment: I've dropped the changing rect's, autolayout and constraints where causing too much headache.  CGaffinetransforms are yielding better results, but still not great.  thinking of snapshoting and splicing the snapshot into multiple snapshots and transforming each one.

Comment: @Augie I had the same problems as you, you may be interested in my solution below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The iOS7 calendar animations are, I think, done with collection view animated transition layouts, which are wonderful but not quite what you want for this situation. Also, they seem to keep you within the same view controller which may not be appropriate for a master-detail scenario as you describe above.

I've been playing with animated transitions recently and have found that the new snapshot views available in iOS7 are brilliant for this sort of thing.

I'm a huge fan of auto layout but transition animations using constraints are far too complicated. However, you can assume that at the start of a transition, your views are already laid out, so you can apply the following principles:

- Add the incoming view to your view hierarchy
- Create a blank canvas view on top of this
- Create a snapshot of your outgoing view (s) and add this to the canvas
- Create a snapshot of your incoming view (s) and add this to the canvas
- Perform the animations between the two
- Remove the canvas

Because the layout has already happened, you can use the `center` or `frame` properties of your existing views on these snapshots, and just animate those. It makes the code much easier to read. This is what Augie's comment above is getting at.

In your case, you can get the effect you are after by tying the various views of the selected cell to the views of the incoming controller, and animating them to their new positions.

I've made an example project with this transition, available [on GitHub](https://github.com/jrturton/UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioningExample). The final effect looks like this:

[image: example video]

This is just a quick example to show how the animation could be performed. In production code, you'd probably make participating controllers conform to a protocol where they returned a number of views for use in transitioning rather than exposing the properties directly and tying the transition to those specific classes.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really interesting technique. I'm not sure I entirely understand what's going on, but I'm looking forward to digging into it and figuring it out.

Comment: Happy to add more detail if there are specific parts you don't follow. Just let me know.

Comment: @jrturton this is pretty great, but I wanted to ask if this is still a valid implementation and if snapshots were performant? I'm curious why you couldn't just animate the labels directly? 

Another question would be what if you only had the image to move into position and then other elements that were new, would it make sense to fade them in? Maybe just fade out the canvas background color?

I'm attempting to replicate Material Design Transitions in Android.

Comment: @user1416564 yes, this is still valid and yes, snapshots give good performance. Animating the labels directly clashes with autolayout and leaves the views of your participating view controllers all messed up. Snapshots on a canvas view leave you with no cleanup other than removing the canvas view.

Comment: @jrturton I was successfullly able to implement this using your git hub project but had some problems with the convertToRect method working and also trying to figure out a way to make it for something production ready.

Comment: @user1416564 then you should ask a separate question