# Make UIScrollView scroll from scrolling inside OR outside of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Say I have a `UIScrollView` that scrolls horizontally just fine. It's height is around 50px. After usability testing, a lot of people are trying to scroll the contents by panning outside of it. Here is the setup:

**Where it says "Amount" is the scrollview**
[image]

I am wondering if it is possible to attach a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the blurred background it sits on top of and have it scroll along with that as well. If this is possible, could someone give me a start on what that approach would possibly look like?

Comment: yes... maybe bigger scroll view and set contentInset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah, the simple solution is simply **make the scroll view bigger** .. it's just that simple.

Have it mostly transparent, with your content sitting where you want it.

What you describe in your question is **a good idea** but it's **extremely! hard** to really implement well, a total pain.  You simply "make the scroll view bigger".

Nice looking app.

These may be relevant to you...

[The UICollectionView "swipe-away" in iOS7 app manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008843/the-uicollectionview-swipe-away-in-ios7-app-manager)

[Show/hide UIToolbar, "match finger movement", precisely as in for example iOS7 Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929220/show-hide-uitoolbar-match-finger-movement-precisely-as-in-for-example-ios7-s)